# Why do images load but show as broken in drupal?

Tags: php, jquery, internet-explorer-8, drupal-7

I have to retrofit a modernly scripted Drupal image gallery to work in ie8. My workaround (to maintain client uploaded content) is to use PHP to read the directory to where the images are uploaded. Then spit out whatever is within. The following code is injected instead of the existing gallery via jQuery:

```
$folder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'sites/default/files/styles/borealis_640x480_respondxl/public/portfolio/';
$filetype = '*.*';
$files = glob($folder.$filetype);
$count = count($files);
echo '<table>';
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    echo '<tr><td>';
    echo '<a name="'.$i.'" href="#'.$i.'"><img src="'.$files[$i].'" /></a>';
    echo substr($files[$i],strlen($folder),strpos($files[$i], '.')-strlen($folder));
    echo '</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

The images are "showing up" but appear as broken. Any solutions?

I've removed the ie8 only exception for development purposes
http://museum.shepherddev.com/portfolio/col3

ps I asked this on Drupal answers but the moderator said it was more of a stack exchange question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the `/` at the start of the string:

```
echo '<a name="'.$i.'" href="#'.$i.'"><img src="/'.$files[$i].'" /></a>';
```

The image urls should start with `/` since you need absolute paths.